# rails4 activerecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I had this setup in my app:

```
User has_many :products
User has_many :product_leads, through: :products
Product belongs_to :user   # (in products table there is user_id)
ProductLead belongs_to :product # (in product_leads table there is no user_id)
ProductLead belongs_to :user
```

With this setup `user.product_leads` is working but `product_lead.user` is not. So I deleted the last line.

I don't have `user_id` in the `product_leads` table, but I don't even want to. ProductLead form is filled as nested attribute together with Product form.

Is there a better way to define `product_lead.user` than below? Or should I rather have `user_id` in the `product_leads` table?

**product_lead.rb**

```
def user
  product.user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `has_one :through` association would help you.

```
def ProductLead < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :product
  has_one :user, through: :product
  # ... other code
end
```

Comment: This would require the task of swapping the `product_id` foreign key in `ProductLead` to instead be `product_lead_id` in the `products` table, but that obstacle aside, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the approach you've proposed as long as it's read-only you don't need to assign a `user` to a `product`.

You should, however, guard against calling `user` on nil in the case `product` doesn't exist:

```
def user
  product.try(:user)  # Only call `user` if product is non-nil.
end
```

Comment: Anthony, I use both `validates :user, presence: true` in the model and `t.integer  "user_id", null: false` in the db. Still you would recommend using `try`?